# Method for computing the similarity between two algorithms

Tags: algorithms

Are there any methods for computing the "similarity" between two algorithms? Intuitively, selection sort and merge sort are more similar to each other than merge sort and radix sort. I want a formal method that computes an algorithm similarity metric.

I know similarity is vaguely defined here. I'm interested in any published method that tries to formalize it somehow.

Comment: Searching for *parse trees* (with the option to use tree transformation/"optimisation" to reduce the effect of differences in notation) used for this purpose brought up articles on *plagiarism detection* as well as on *program similarity*.

Comment: @greybeard this is a cool lead, thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't this allow you to solve the Function Problem?

Comment: @JörgWMittag approximate solutions are fine for me. Humans can clearly do it in some form (e.g. I could ask you how similar two algorithms are and you could give me a reasonable answer) -- I'm just looking for a formalism of that.